# Getting random LCK_M_SCH_M on convert and bulk insert task

Tags: ssis, locking

I starting getting random LCK_M_SCH_M locks with huge wait time, which hung my etl proccess.

The ssis package runs like this:

I have 4 containers that run in parallel and do the same thing:

- Convert a tab delimited file from unicode->utf8
- Truncate the table
- Bulk insert the data
  [image]

Also transactionoption is set to NotSupported.

What could be causing the lock?

All foreach loops do not overlap ragarding tables/files.

Do they contest somehow?

Comment: Are you truncating or actually using DELETE?  I thought I should ask in case there are FKs on the tables.  Truncate will take a schema lock,  though this should not affect other tables.  Are there any constraints or triggers on the target tables?  Can you look at `sys.dm_tran_locks` to confirm which objects are taking schema locks?

Comment: The LCK_M_SCH_M lock means that your truncate is waiting on another operation to release a schema stability lock (which is held for everything, even selects with NOLOCK). It's likely you have some other process with an open connection.

Comment: what are the objects involved here? if you know how to get the waits then i'd surmise you know how to get the locked objects (wait resource).

Comment: I am actually running truncate table command in the loops. I will separarte the truncates in a separate foreach loop before the main loop in order to run in sequence...